What are the most useful AI features in smartphones for daily tasks?
I’ve been super curious about the AI stuff in smartphones lately. I know it’s everywhere now, but I’m not sure what’s actually useful for everyday stuff. Like, I’ve heard about voice assistants, camera improvements, or apps that suggest things—but I don’t know what really makes life easier.
I haven’t explored much myself, just used Google Assistant a bit and the AI photo edits on my phone. But there’s so much more out there, and I’m not sure where to start or what’s worth using.
If you’ve found some cool AI features that actually help you day-to-day, I’d love to hear about it. Also, are there any hidden gems I should try?
